# Touch Slide over UIButton issue

Tags: objective-c, swift

Can someone tell me if I have translated the first 2 lines correctly to Swift and if the first part is correctly? Also, could anyone help me figure out the rest. I can't figure out how to translate the if statement at the bottom..

```
[C addTarget:self action:@selector(outsideOfKey: forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside|UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[C addTarget:self action:@selector(keyGetsLeft: forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside | UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(void) outsideOfKey:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{    
    for(UITouch *t in [event allTouches])
{

        CGPoint touchPoint = [t locationInView:window];
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(C.frame, touchPoint))
         {
             C.highlighted = YES;
         }
        else{
            C.highlighted = NO;
        }
```

Translated to swift

```
C.addTarget(self, action:Selector("outsideOfKey:forEvent:"), forControlEvents:.TouchDragOutside)
    C.addTarget(self, action:Selector("outsideOfKey:forEvent:"), forControlEvents:.TouchDragInside)
    C.addTarget(self, action:Selector("keyGetsLeft:forEvent:"), forControlEvents:.TouchUpOutside)
    C.addTarget(self, action:Selector("keyGetsLeft:forEvent:"), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)


func outsideOfKey (sender: AnyObject, forEvent: UIEvent) {


    let touch = event.allTouches() as? UITouch

        for touch
        {
            var touchPoint : CGPoint = touch.locationInView(window)

            if(CGRectContainsPoint(C.frame, touchPoint))
            {
                C.highlighted = YES;
            }
            else{
                C.highlighted = NO;
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
C.addTarget(self, action:Selector("outsideOfKey:forEvent:"), forControlEvents:.TouchDragOutside | .TouchDragInside)
C.addTarget(self, action:Selector("keyGetsLeft:forEvent:"), forControlEvents:.TouchUpOutside | .TouchUpInside)


func outsideOfKey(sender: AnyObject, forEvent event: UIEvent) {

    if let touches = event.allTouches()?.allObjects as? [UITouch] {

        for touch in touches {
            var touchPoint : CGPoint = touch.locationInView(window)

            if CGRectContainsPoint(C.frame, touchPoint) == true {
                C.highlighted = true;
            } else {
                C.highlighted = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Points:

- You can still use the "|" operator on enums in swift (most of the time)
- You don't put parentheses around the conditional clause in swift
- YES and NO are not valid in swift, you much use true and false
- Swift does not support sets so it is easiest to get the touches as an Array so you can iterate using a simple swift for...in loop
- The "if let ..." pattern is called optional binding, if the right hand side is not nil "touches" will be set to the value and the code in the following braces will be executed, otherwise it will skip the block of code
- The way "?" is used after ".allTouches()" is called optional chaining, if .allTouches() returns nil, the whole expression will return nil

Hope this is of some use to you, let me know if you have any more swift queries!